# Requiring external JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy, commonjs

After reading all the relevant answers in SO and posts in the Appcelerator forums I still can't get this to work:

I have an application developed in Appcelerator, and I want to load an [external JavaScript file](https://github.com/hglattergotz/indicatordemo/blob/master/Resources/lib/IndicatorWindow.js) in some of my controllers.

My App structure is as follows:

```
+ app
    - assets
    - controllers
    - models
    + lib
        - IndicatorWindow.js
    ...
```

Inside a controller I have the following code:

```
var uie = require('lib/IndicatorWindow');
```

But when I run this on an Android phone I get:

> **Uncaught Error:** Requested module not found: lib/IndicatorWindow

I have also tried placing the `lib` folder outside of `app`, and using other paths such as `/lib/IndicatorWindow` and `app/lib/IndicatorWindow`.

I even tried using `Ti.include()` instead, with the same result. But I would rather use `require()` since I prefer using CommonJS modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a lib folder inside assets folder and paste the js file there and you would be able to require file just like you do in classic :)

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that it had to be inside `assets` ;)

Comment: It doesn't. Files from lib directory are accessed without `lib/`. Anyway moving it to assets will work too.

Answer (score 2):

just use var uie = require('IndicatorWindow');

Also make sure it uses exports inside the JS

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem was that I had to place the lib folder inside the assets folder.