# How to use babel into appcelerator project?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, babeljs

I'm importend in my workspace, a project build in appcelerator.
So I have some error like this:

[image]

If I open any file, I have this situation:

[image]

I don't know, how to fix this.
So this is my plugin.js

```
"use strict";

exports.__esModule = true;

var _getIterator2 = require("babel-runtime/core-js/get-iterator");

var _getIterator3 = _interopRequireDefault(_getIterator2);

var _classCallCheck2 = require("babel-runtime/helpers/classCallCheck");

var _classCallCheck3 = _interopRequireDefault(_classCallCheck2);

var _possibleConstructorReturn2 = require("babel-runtime/helpers/possibleConstructorReturn");

var _possibleConstructorReturn3 = _interopRequireDefault(_possibleConstructorReturn2);

var _inherits2 = require("babel-runtime/helpers/inherits");

var _inherits3 = _interopRequireDefault(_inherits2);

var _optionManager = require("./file/options/option-manager");

var _optionManager2 = _interopRequireDefault(_optionManager);

var _babelMessages = require("babel-messages");

var messages = _interopRequireWildcard(_babelMessages);

var _store = require("../store");

var _store2 = _interopRequireDefault(_store);

var _babelTraverse = require("babel-traverse");

var _babelTraverse2 = _interopRequireDefault(_babelTraverse);

var _assign = require("lodash/assign");

var _assign2 = _interopRequireDefault(_assign);

var _clone = require("lodash/clone");

var _clone2 = _interopRequireDefault(_clone);

function _interopRequireWildcard(obj) { if (obj && obj.__esModule) { return obj; } else { var newObj = {}; if (obj != null) { for (var key in obj) { if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) newObj[key] = obj[key]; } } newObj.default = obj; return newObj; } }

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

/* eslint max-len: 0 */

var GLOBAL_VISITOR_PROPS = ["enter", "exit"];

var Plugin = function (_Store) {
  (0, _inherits3.default)(Plugin, _Store);

  function Plugin(plugin, key) {
    (0, _classCallCheck3.default)(this, Plugin);

    var _this = (0, _possibleConstructorReturn3.default)(this, _Store.call(this));

    _this.initialized = false;
    _this.raw = (0, _assign2.default)({}, plugin);
    _this.key = key;

    _this.manipulateOptions = _this.take("manipulateOptions");
    _this.post = _this.take("post");
    _this.pre = _this.take("pre");
    _this.visitor = _this.normaliseVisitor((0, _clone2.default)(_this.take("visitor")) || {});
    return _this;
  }

  Plugin.prototype.take = function take(key) {
    var val = this.raw[key];
    delete this.raw[key];
    return val;
  };

  Plugin.prototype.chain = function chain(target, key) {
    if (!target[key]) return this[key];
    if (!this[key]) return target[key];

    var fns = [target[key], this[key]];

    return function () {
      var val = void 0;

      for (var _len = arguments.length, args = Array(_len), _key = 0; _key < _len; _key++) {
        args[_key] = arguments[_key];
      }

      for (var _iterator = fns, _isArray = Array.isArray(_iterator), _i = 0, _iterator = _isArray ? _iterator : (0, _getIterator3.default)(_iterator);;) {
        var _ref;

        if (_isArray) {
          if (_i >= _iterator.length) break;
          _ref = _iterator[_i++];
        } else {
          _i = _iterator.next();
          if (_i.done) break;
          _ref = _i.value;
        }

        var fn = _ref;

        if (fn) {
          var ret = fn.apply(this, args);
          if (ret != null) val = ret;
        }
      }
      return val;
    };
  };

  Plugin.prototype.maybeInherit = function maybeInherit(loc) {
    var inherits = this.take("inherits");
    if (!inherits) return;

    inherits = _optionManager2.default.normalisePlugin(inherits, loc, "inherits");

    this.manipulateOptions = this.chain(inherits, "manipulateOptions");
    this.post = this.chain(inherits, "post");
    this.pre = this.chain(inherits, "pre");
    this.visitor = _babelTraverse2.default.visitors.merge([inherits.visitor, this.visitor]);
  };

  /**
   * We lazy initialise parts of a plugin that rely on contextual information such as
   * position on disk and how it was specified.
   */

  Plugin.prototype.init = function init(loc, i) {
    if (this.initialized) return;
    this.initialized = true;

    this.maybeInherit(loc);

    for (var key in this.raw) {
      throw new Error(messages.get("pluginInvalidProperty", loc, i, key));
    }
  };

  Plugin.prototype.normaliseVisitor = function normaliseVisitor(visitor) {
    for (var _iterator2 = GLOBAL_VISITOR_PROPS, _isArray2 = Array.isArray(_iterator2), _i2 = 0, _iterator2 = _isArray2 ? _iterator2 : (0, _getIterator3.default)(_iterator2);;) {
      var _ref2;

      if (_isArray2) {
        if (_i2 >= _iterator2.length) break;
        _ref2 = _iterator2[_i2++];
      } else {
        _i2 = _iterator2.next();
        if (_i2.done) break;
        _ref2 = _i2.value;
      }

      var key = _ref2;

      if (visitor[key]) {
        throw new Error("Plugins aren't allowed to specify catch-all enter/exit handlers. Please target individual nodes.");
      }
    }

    _babelTraverse2.default.explode(visitor);
    return visitor;
  };

  return Plugin;
}(_store2.default);

exports.default = Plugin;
module.exports = exports["default"];
```

How can I fixed it?

Comment: are you sure you are importing correctly? looks like a referencing issue

Answer (score 0):

***import*** syntax is from ECMAScript 6 - which is yet to be added in the Appcelerator Studio.

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-6927

Comment: thanks for your answer. But If is possible to import this module in Appcelerator Studio? How?

Comment: In general, to use external js files - follow this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008218/requiring-external-javascript-file. But you can't import external projects into Studio workspace and use it directly. If js file is having unsupported syntax it will error out by the studio and as well as Alloy compiler during the build.